# Why can't you mix Aggregate values and Non-Aggregate values in a single SELECT?

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I know that if you have one aggregate function in a SELECT statement, then all the other values in the statement must be either aggregate functions, or listed in a GROUP BY clause. I don't understand *why* that's the case.

If I do:

```
SELECT Name, 'Jones' AS Surname FROM People
```

I get:

```
NAME    SURNAME
Dave    Jones
Susan   Jones
Amy     Jones
```

So, the DBMS has taken a value from each row, and appended a single value to it in the result set. That's fine. But if that works, why can't I do:

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(Name) AS Surname FROM People
```

It seems like the same idea, take a value from each row and append a single value. But instead of:

```
NAME    SURNAME
Dave    3
Susan   3
Amy     3
```

I get:

> You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'ContactName' as part of an aggregate function.

I know it's not allowed, but the two circumstances seem so similar that I don't understand why. Is it to make the DBMS easier to implement? If anyone can explain to me why it doesn't work like I think it should, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: what do you expect `count(Name)` to mean in that query?

Comment: Some RDBM systems (like SQL-Server, Postgres) have "windowing" functions that can show results similar to what you seek. When you use `GROUP BY` either explicitely or implicitely (by using aggregate functions in the `SELECT` part), you can't have both.

Comment: I too say take a look at `PARTITION BY` in an `OVER ()` clause, which tend to appear closer together in a query, and thing may begin to click into place. I sometimes wish SQL was a little less structured :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Aggregates doesn't work on a complete result, they only work on a group in a result.

Consider a table containing:

```
Person   Pet
-------- --------
Amy      Cat
Amy      Dog
Amy      Canary
Dave     Dog
Susan    Snake
Susan    Spider
```

If you use a query that groups on Person, it will divide the data into these groups:

```
Amy:
  Amy    Cat
  Amy    Dog
  Amy    Canary
Dave:
  Dave   Dog
Susan:
  Susan  Snake
  Susan  Spider
```

If you use an aggreage, for exmple the count aggregate, it will produce one result for each group:

```
Amy:
  Amy    Cat
  Amy    Dog
  Amy    Canary    count(*) = 3
Dave:
  Dave   Dog       count(*) = 1
Susan:
  Susan  Snake
  Susan  Spider    count(*) = 2
```

So, the query `select Person, count(*) from People group by Person` gives you one record for each group:

```
Amy    3
Dave   1
Susan  2
```

If you try to get the Pet field in the result also, that doesn't work because there may be multiple values for that field in each group.

(Some databases, like MySQL, does allow that anyway, and just returns any random value from within the group, and it's your responsibility to know if the result is sensible or not.)

If you use an aggregate, but doesn't specify any grouping, the query will still be grouped, and the entire result is a single group. So the query `select count(*) from Person` will create a single group containing all records, and the aggregate can count the records in that group. The result contains one row from each group, and as there is only one group, there will be one row in the result.

Answer (score 8):

Think about it this way: when you call COUNT without grouping, it "collapses" the table to a single group making it impossible to access the individual items within a group in a select clause.

You can still get your result using a subquery or a cross join:

```
    SELECT p1.Name, COUNT(p2.Name) AS Surname FROM People p1 CROSS JOIN People p2 GROUP BY p1.Name

    SELECT Name, (SELECT COUNT(Name) FROM People) AS Surname FROM People
```

Comment: I think he wants the subquery to be `(SELECT COUNT(p.Name) FROM People p WHERE p.Name = People.Name)`, rather than a whole count.

Comment: Be careful with CROSS JOIN; if you CROSS JOIN a large table to another large table, the result will be huge (it multiples the rows in table1 x table2) If you have 10,000 rows in each CROSS JOIN gives you 100,000,000 rows. I only use CROSS JOIN with small, fixed tables, usually a list of months in one year.

Comment: @ZeroK fortunately, RDBMS are smart enough to optimize the execution plan. If you look at the actual execution plan of the first statement that MS SQL builds you will see that it calculates COUNT aggregates before joining. So there's no point at time you or RDBMS actually have to deal with the whole cartesian product of two row sets.

Answer (score 7):

As others explained, when you have a `GROUP BY` or you are using an aggregate function like `COUNT()` in the `SELECT` list, you are doing a grouping of rows and therefore collapsing matching rows into one for every group.

When you only use aggregate functions in the `SELECT` list, without `GROUP BY`, think of it as you have a `GROUP BY 1`, so all rows are grouped, collapsed into one. So, if you have a hundred rows, the database can't really show you a name as there are a hundred of them.

However, for RDBMSs that have "windowing" functions, what you want is feasible. E.g. use aggregate functions without a `GROUP BY`.

Example for SQL-Server, where all rows (names) in the table are counted:

```
SELECT Name
     , COUNT(*) OVER() AS cnt
FROM People
```

How does the above work?

- It shows the `Name` like the
  `COUNT(*) OVER() AS cnt` did not
  exist and
- It shows the `COUNT(*)` like if it was making a total grouping of the
  table.

---

Another example. If you have a `Surname` field on the table, you can have something like this to show all rows grouped by Surname and counting how many people have same Surname:

```
SELECT Name
     , Surname
     , COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Surname) AS cnt
FROM People
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query implicitly asks for different types of rows in your result set, and that is not allowed. All rows returned should be of the same type and have the same kind of columns.

'SELECT name, surname' wants to returns a row for every row in the table.

'SELECT COUNT(*)' wants to return a single row combining the results of all the rows in the table.

I think you're correct that in this case the database could plausibly just do both queries and then copy the result of 'SELECT COUNT(*)' into every result. One reason for not doing this is that it would be a stealth performance hit: you'd effectively be doing an extra self-join without declaring it anywhere.

Other answers have explained how to write a working version of this query, so I won't go into that.

Comment: +1. But,COUNT(*) wants to return a single value. 'Jones' wants to return a single value. Why is one allowed, but the other isn't?

Answer (score 1):

The aggregate function and the group by clause aren't separate things, they're parts of the same thing that appear in different places in the query. If you wish to aggregate on a column, you must say what function to use for aggregation; if you wish to have an aggregation function, it has to be applied over some column.

Comment: -1. This doesn't answer the question - "Why can't you mix aggregate values and non-aggregate values".

Comment: It answers the question as stated, of why the engine doesn't allow you to have a count without a group by. You should be able to figure out the rest. It may not be thorough or long, but that doesn't mean it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: It does answer the question "why the engine doesn't allow you to have a count without a group by". That's not the question "Why can't you mix aggregate values and non-aggregate values?" I'm not saying you're wrong - you're obviously right. But it's not an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

The aggregate function takes values from multiple rows with a specific condition and combines them into one value. This condition is defined by the `GROUP BY`in your statement. So you can't use an aggregate function without a `GROUP BY`

With

```
SELECT Name, 'Jones' AS Surname FROM People
```

you simply select an additional column with a fixed value... but with

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(Name) AS Surname FROM People GROUP BY Name
```

you tell the DBMS to select the Names, remember how often every Name occured in the table and collapse them into one row. So if you omit the `GROUP BY` the DBMS can't tell, how to collapse the records