# Number of tuples outputted by GROUP BY primitive

Tags: sql, relational-database

My question is related to the semantic of SQL's `GROUP BY` primitive.
Suppose that we have the following relation (Users):

```
+----+------+---------------+-----+
| id | name | country       | age |
+----+------+---------------+-----+
| 1  | Foo  | Brazil        | 20  |
| 2  | Bar  | Japan         | 20  |
| 3  | Baz  | Brazil        | 22  |
| 4  | Quz  | Brazil        | 18  |
+----+------+---------------+-----+
```

I expected that the following dummy query:

```
SELECT name, country, avg(age)
FROM Users
GROUP BY country
```

returns four tuples, since we used a non-grouped attribute in the `SELECT` projection:

```
+------+---------------+-----+
| name | country       | age |
+------+---------------+-----+
| Foo  | Brazil        | 20  |
| Bar  | Japan         | 20  |
| Baz  | Brazil        | 20  |
| Quz  | Brazil        | 20  |
+------+---------------+-----+
```

Yet, it yields the following tuples:

```
+------+---------------+-----+
| name | country       | age |
+------+---------------+-----+
| Foo  | Brazil        | 20  |
| Bar  | Japan         | 20  |
+------+---------------+-----+
```

Why?

**Edit: found out that [Why can't you mix Aggregate values and Non-Aggregate values in a single SELECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920070/why-cant-you-mix-aggregate-values-and-non-aggregate-values-in-a-single-select) answers this question.**

Comment: This should have thrown an error due to the lack of `name` being in the `GROUP BY` clause...  what DBMS is this?

Comment: Mysql,for example, allows indeterminate results when you dont use an aggregate function on a column not in the GROUP BY.Almost all others dbs throw an error

Comment: @Siyual I did not test on a real database, since I do not have access to one here. I *tested* on w3schools online db, and it returned these tuples. My question is more related to what is the expected outcome? Is it an error?

Comment: It seems that my questoin has been answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920070/why-cant-you-mix-aggregate-values-and-non-aggregate-values-in-a-single-select. I'll close the question

Comment: let me guess... mySQL database?  read up on mySQL extensions.. it extends group by's so that if you don't put non-aggregated fields in the group by, the system is free to choose any value. that's right.. ANY. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-handling.html "The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate."