# SQL Query assistance - Looping through data query

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables. Config and Data. Config table has info to define what I call "Predefined Points". The columns are configId, machineId, iotype, ioid, subfield and predeftype. I have a second table that contains all the data for all the items in the config table linked by configId. Data table contains configId, timestamp, value.

I am trying to return each row from the config table with 2 new columns in the result which would be min timestamp of this particular predefined point and max timestamp of this particular predefined point.

Pseudocode would be

```
select a.*, min(b.timestamp), max(b.timestamp) from TrendConfig a join TrendData b on a.configId = b.configId where configId = (select configId from TrendConfig)
```

Where the subquery would return multiple values.

[image: Table structure image]

Any idea how to formulate this?

Comment: Please show us table structure so that an exact answer can be given.  Most likely this could be done via a join or correlated subquery.

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about a join- https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Tim, I included an image of the structure.

Comment: Jeff, indeed but my big question is how do I get all items from Config table and get the min/max timestamp for EACH, that's the tough part for me. 

Say there are 2 items in config (configId = 1, configId = 2). I need to get all the rows from Config where configId = 1 and a new column for min(timestamp) where configId = 1 and max(timestamp) where configId = 1 and then again the same for configId = 2 on a second row.

Comment: You want one output row for each value? Sounds like GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

Try an inner join:

select a.*, b.min(timestamp), b.max(timestamp)
from config a
inner join data b
on a.configId = b.configID

Comment: It ran with with min(b.timestamp) and max(b.timestamp) but only returned a single result... because it's only getting the max/min for all points instead of for each point in Config table.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find an answer using: [Why can't you mix Aggregate values and Non-Aggregate values in a single SELECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920070/why-cant-you-mix-aggregate-values-and-non-aggregate-values-in-a-single-select)

The solution was indeed GROUP BY as CL mentioned above.

select a.*, min(b.timestamp), max(b.timestamp) from TrendConfig a join TrendData b on a.configId = b.configId group by a.configId