# (Doctrine with Symfony 4) Aggregate functions along with a regular DQL statement?

Tags: count, aggregate, dql

I have the following DQL statement, using Doctrine's querybuilder:

As you can see I am bringing back all the posts and their comments:

```
public function getAllPosts(User $user){

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');
    $qb->select('p, postPhotos,postVideos, comments, commentUser, commentUserPhoto, replyComments, commentReplyUser, commentReplyUserPhoto, postTier,creator,creatorPhoto,creatorTiers,creatorSubscriptions')
        ->leftJoin('p.photos', 'postPhotos')
        ->leftJoin('p.videos', 'postVideos')
        ->leftJoin('p.comments', 'comments')
        ->leftJoin('comments.user', 'commentUser')
        ->leftJoin('commentUser.photos', 'commentUserPhoto', 'WITH', 'commentUserPhoto.type = :profileType')
        ->leftJoin('comments.children', 'replyComments')
```

I have already tried adding a

```
->addSelect("COUNT(p.comments) as countComments")
```

And I just get an error, "countComments' does not point to a Class"

So I looked up other references, like this one: https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/doctrine-queries/select-sum

But it doesn't give an example of how to include a count in with the results of a DQL query.

Do I need to just create my own count function within the comments repository, and loop through my original data set, calling it once per post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There 2 issues with what you are trying to do:

1) You should use the **join alias "comments"**, not the relation field "p.comments", in the aggregate function:

```
->addSelect("COUNT(comments) as countComments")
```

and the query will be **grouped by** the root entity, unless `->groupBy()` is specified.

But this is not a solution in your case, the real issue is that:

2) You cannot **select fields of a table** when you are trying to **aggregate any of its field**. It will not work and will produce strange results. More specific, you will get just one entity in the result collection.

More [why cant you mix aggregate values and non aggregate values in a single select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920070/why-cant-you-mix-aggregate-values-and-non-aggregate-values-in-a-single-select)

***Solution in your case***

Since you are already selecting the "comments", just ***"count"*** the collection resulted:

```
$posts = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
foreach($posts as $post) {
    echo $post->getComments()->count();
}
```

or

```
$posts = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
foreach($posts as $post) {
    echo count($post['comments']);
}
```

References:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html