# Join multiple tables with getting total number of rows from 3rd table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Trying to join 4 - 5 tables at once as of wanted to grab multiple data which is stored in 5 tables on in 5th table i am trying to count total number of players that have been joined the tournament this is working fine but the main problem which I am facing here is when there is not data in the main table it still return me 1 row with all fields as null except total players showing 0 as it shown not return any rows can anyone help em out below is my query

```
    $getTournamentData = $this->db->select('tournament.*, tournament_meta.meta_title, tournament_meta.meta_description, categories.title AS category, categories.slug AS category_slug, games.game_name, games.slug AS game_slug, count(tournament_players.id) AS total_players');
    $getTournamentData = $this->db->join('categories', 'categories.id = tournament.category_id');
    $getTournamentData = $this->db->join('games', 'games.game_id = tournament.game_id');
    $getTournamentData = $this->db->join('tournament_meta', 'tournament_meta.post_id = tournament.id');
    $getTournamentData = $this->db->join('tournament_players', 'tournament_players.tournamentID = tournament.id', 'left');


    $dataCond['created_by'] = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

    if($id != null) {
        $dataCond['tournament.id'] = $id;
    }

    $getTournamentData = $this->db->where($dataCond);
    $getTournamentData = $this->db->get('tournament');
```

so in return total_players are showing 0 and rest all is null because no data is insterted in the table yet show it should not return any data from the database

Comment: ```COUNT(DISTINCT table3.primary_key_expression)```

Comment: @Akina STILL RETURNING ME 1 ROW WITH total_players as 0

Comment: Remove the third argument ( `left` ) here: `$this->db->join('tournament_players', 'tournament_players.tournamentID = tournament.id', 'left');`

Comment: SELECT `tournament`.*, `tournament_meta`.`meta_title`, `tournament_meta`.`meta_description`, `categories`.`title` AS `category`, `categories`.`slug` AS `category_slug`, `games`.`game_name`, `games`.`slug` AS `game_slug`, count(DISTINCT tournament_players.id) AS total_players FROM `tournament` JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.`id` = `tournament`.`category_id` JOIN `games` ON `games`.`game_id` = `tournament`.`game_id` JOIN `tournament_meta` ON `tournament_meta`.`post_id` = `tournament`.`id` JOIN `tournament_players` ON `tournament_players`.`tournamentID` = `tournament`.`id`

Comment: @Marleen after removing third the printed query is a follows but it is still returning me 1 row tournament table and rest all tables are empty

Comment: anyone here to help me out ?

Comment: use count method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing an aggregate function (`count()`) with plain column names in your `SELECT` clause and that is giving unexpected results.
See: [Why can't you mix Aggregate values and Non-Aggregate values in a single SELECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920070/why-cant-you-mix-aggregate-values-and-non-aggregate-values-in-a-single-select)

You can fix this by adding a `GROUP BY` clause with all of the column names from the `SELECT` clause, except for the column name that has the `count()` on it. Be sure to fully type out all of the column names for the `tournament.*` in the `GROUP BY`, so use `tournament.id, tournament.category_id, tournament.game_id` etc instead:

```
SELECT tournament.*, tournament_meta.meta_title, tournament_meta.meta_description, categories.title AS category, categories.slug AS category_slug, games.game_name, games.slug AS game_slug, count(tournament_players.id) AS total_players
FROM tournament
JOIN categories ON categories.id = tournament.category_id
JOIN games ON games.game_id = tournament.game_id
JOIN tournament_meta ON tournament_meta.post_id = tournament.id
JOIN tournament_players ON tournament_players.tournamentID = tournament.id
GROUP BY
tournament.id, tournament.category_id, tournament.game_id,
-- add other tournament colums here --
tournament_meta.meta_title, tournament_meta.meta_description, categories.title, categories.slug, games.game_name, games.slug
```

In CodeIgniter (3) this would translate to:

```
$this->db->select('tournament.*, tournament_meta.meta_title, tournament_meta.meta_description, categories.title AS category, categories.slug AS category_slug, games.game_name, games.slug AS game_slug, count(tournament_players.id) AS total_players');
$this->db->from('tournament');
$this->db->join('categories', 'categories.id = tournament.category_id');
$this->db->join('games', 'games.game_id = tournament.game_id');
$this->db->join('tournament_meta', 'tournament_meta.post_id = tournament.id');
$this->db->join('tournament_players', 'tournament_players.tournamentID = tournament.id');
$this->db->group_by('tournament.id, tournament.category_id, tournament.game_id,
/* add other tournament columns here */
tournament_meta.meta_title, tournament_meta.meta_description, categories.title, categories.slug, games.game_name, games.slug');
```

Alternatively you can use a subselect, in which case you can remove the join to the `tournament_players` table:

```
SELECT tournament.*, tournament_meta.meta_title, tournament_meta.meta_description, categories.title AS category, categories.slug AS category_slug, games.game_name, games.slug AS game_slug, (
    SELECT count(id)
    FROM tournament_players
    WHERE tournament_players.tournamentID = tournament.id) AS total_players
FROM tournament
JOIN categories ON categories.id = tournament.category_id
JOIN games ON games.game_id = tournament.game_id
JOIN tournament_meta ON tournament_meta.post_id = tournament.id
```

Use with `$this->db->query()` in CodeIgniter.

I haven't tested these queries obviously, so there may be errors.
Hopefully this'll help you get started.

Comment: awesome working fine now but if the record exist it's duplicating the rows :( I am using your last provided query

Comment: Do you have multiple `meta_title`s/`meta_description`s per tournament? That could be causing the duplication.

Comment: My bad you are right so what should I do know as i meta title there are 4 rows attached to this tournament i beleive 2 so i need meta data as wel this means i have to create another query to get meta data right

Comment: Yes, if you want all of the meta data for the tournament, then leave out the join to the meta table and create a separate query to get the meta data for the tournament.